# Nicest way to solve stringified floating rounding issue through algorithm? (Java, JEval)

Tags: java, floating-point, double, rounding, precision

I have an output operation from JEval that is an string with the float imprecision, something like "1.56700000001". I need some approach to hold the maximum precision but correcting the float imprecision. Perhaps some efficient algorithm that makes the most exact thing without being wrong.

If I´m not wrong, any double with not exact binary representation will be output´d if so in a String of length() 18, with the precision = (14 minus - point char - integer part).

So we can round to the precision-1 (last) digit when the string is clearly using all the bits without trailing zeroes (as JEval dont show them, this means when length() == 18 ).

The only problem would be if the original string has a real expected full value and needs not rounding, in  that case we only would loose one digit of precision.
What do you think of this approach. Is it a better way?

For example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class test {
    private final static int THREESHOLD = 3; // num of decimals from which 
                                             // we consider that they represent a floating 
                                             // representation inaccuracy in case every double´s 
                                             //digit is used with no traliing zeroes ending

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] JEvalOutput = {"1.5555000000000001", //Rounding is needed
                                "234455555.29",       //Rounding is not needed
                                "455656.45599999998", //Rounding is needed
                                "111132323232334.19", //Here there is a problem, should be rounded??? 
                                                      //Thats why we use THREESHOLD var, to distinguish when can we consider 
                                "123456789012345678"};//Rounding is not needed

        for (String aux : JEvalOutput){

            int precision = aux.length()-(aux.contains(".")?1:0); 
            if (precision==17 && aux.contains(".") && aux.length()-aux.indexOf('.')-1 >THREESHOLD) precision--;
            BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(aux, new MathContext(precision)).stripTrailingZeros();

            System.out.println(aux + " --> " + a.toPlainString()); //Only First and Third are rounded. 
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
1.5555000000000001 --> 1.5555
234455555.29       --> 234455555.29
455656.45599999998 --> 455656.456
111132323232334.19 --> 111132323232334.19 //If THREESHOLD was 1, then this would be 111(...)34.2
123456789012345678 --> 123456789012345678
```

Is there any cleaner, best practice, professional solution?

Comment: do u want to remove the trailing zero at the end? like 1.125000 gives 1.125 as output.

Comment: see http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/08/double-your-money-again.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. You're welcome.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123.4566661");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0#");
System.out.println(df.format(bd));
```